# Xcode Profile Provisioning Issues

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have registered on Xcode with an account that doesn't have the developer membership and had the profile provisioning to be correct and did some projectsand tested some; now I created another account (a developer account) and I bought the membership now I'm having trouble on the provisioning profile stuff and I can't do the profile provisioning creation, any help with that?!

[image]

**Error:**

> There are no devices registered in your account on the developer website. Plugin and select a device to have Xcode register it.

Answer (score 1):

login to the `developer.apple.com` and `login account` and now you need to `add your device UUID` (`add device`) and save it.

you also have to create app id with current bundle.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to change your bundle identifier, 2 application with same bundle identifier cannot exist.
You are seeing this error because you have registered that bundle identifier with your previous account.

Comment: it should be a comment or provide descriptive answer